# Is it possible to pass class to binding attribute in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

We have a solution based on a numeric field being set to 1 or 2 or displaying certain icons. It works.

```
<span *ngIf="config.icon"
      [class.fas]="true"
      [class.fa-plus]="icon===1"
      [class.fa-minus]="icon===2"
      class="indicator">
</span>
```

I sense what shortly, we'll have a whole bunch of such icons (about 15 different ones). The suggested solution is either to put in 15 lines of specific class assignments or to build a specialized component managing that.

I'm opposed to both but haven't got it working out when I tried and googling led to irrelevant hits. Possibly due to my incompetence recognized th egood stuff.

Is it possible to do something like one of the following **pseudo** code lines? How?

```
      [class.fa-{{iconName}}]="true"
      [class]="iconName"
```

**edit**

Based on the comments/answers, I got it working using the following.

```
<span *ngIf="config.icon"
      [ngClass]='{ "fas": true, "fa-plus": true }'></span>
```

However, for some reason, I'm not getting anything using the syntax below.

```
 <span *ngIf="config.icon"
        [ngClass]="classes"></span>

...
classes: { "fas": true, "fa-plus": true };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngclass).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Sorry for being few-worded. I tried that and got nothing. The tag is *<span [ngClass]="classes"></span>* and in the component I put in a property *classes: { "fas": true, "fa-plus": true };*. Any idea what I might be missing? Checking the markup, I see no class assigned to the tag in Chrome.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Got it! Apparently, one can't assign the value directly in the property (which I though was done waaay before *ngOnInit()* was invoked. Setting the value of the bound class property in *ngOnInit* did the trick.

Comment: Should be `classes =` instead of `classes:`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Sight... You ar eright. It's the dotty colon not the smudged colon (aka equality sign, hehe). That's what you get coming from C#... Now I'm moderately satisfied. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<span class= "indicator"
  [class.fas]="true"
  [ngClass]="'fa-' + iconName">
</span>
```

See working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgecjw

Comment: I suspect it's going to be easier to maintain in the long run if I use *ngClass* from the component, like the link in the comments suggests. Nevertheless, *ngClass* seems to be the right way to go, so green check. Would you rewrite the example so it supports class assignment from component code for +1 too? Like shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngclass).